# when focus is out from date time textbox then onchange event is working in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have one text box which is accepting `datetime` from `user`
other textbox accepting `varchar` `username`

If i select `username` and change `datetime` textbox values it should reset `username` textbox

for this i write following code which is working good `on change values of datetime textbox`

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        validateChangeText('Datetextbox');
    });

    function validateChangeText(ctr) {
        $('#' + ctr).keypress(function () {
            $('#Username').val('');
          });

        $('#' + ctr).change(function () {
            $('#Username').val('');
           });
    }
```

But why it `resets username values` when I only `click on and make focus out of text box` 
not changes any value of datetime then also it `resets usernaem values`
In date time textbox i have using following code.

```
@Model.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
@Html.Hidden("tDate", Model.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
```

Comment: The on change event fires only when the input field is blured out and the value of the input field has changed. If you want to fire the event as the user types in the date input you could use `keyup` or `focus`

Comment: sorry to ask about fiddle use but i'm newbie plz give me any tread

Comment: Your **keypress** event fires when you are clicking on the Datetextbox

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 no thats not the reason. i tested it.

Comment: @ashuthinks check if you are changing the value of the DateTime textbox  in any other method .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you try following...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    validateChangeText('Datetextbox');
});

function validateChangeText(ctr) {
    $('#' + ctr).focus(function () {
        $('#Username').val('');
    });

    $('#' + ctr).change(function () {
        $('#Username').val('');
    });
}
```

Here's js fiddle...[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77dmS/1/)

Comment: not working :(
when i click on datetime textbox and dont change value then also it is reseting username values

Comment: could you please help me i'm new

Comment: You said that "this is working here fine but not in mvc code"...which mvc code you are talking about ?

Comment: `@Model.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss")
@Html.Hidden("tDate", Model.Date.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"))`
and normal code there in javascript for date picker